# will a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP field will update automagically if you run an UPDATE statement against other fields in the table?

Tags: mysql

Will the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP column be updated even if I UPDATE some other column in the row?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking? Are you asking if a `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` field will update automagically if you run an `UPDATE` statement against other fields in the table? That's my best guess venture, but I don't want to post an answer shooting from the hip.

Comment: Sorry I 'm not good for english. yes  if a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP field will update automagically if you run an UPDATE statement against other fields in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you set the auto-update value to be `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, it will always update, regardless of which columns you updated. You don't have to specify the field and set it to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, as it will do it on its own.

Be advised that you cannot have one column with a default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and another column with the auto-update value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

See more in the MySQL docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html).